# I can't pass Fb Profile Picture as multipart/form-data in retrofit as well as in Asyntask in android

Tags: android, image-uploading, retrofit2

I read many tutorial to upload image using retrofit but all articles give me answer to upload img from sdcard or mobile but i want to pass facebook profile picture as multipart/form-data in retrofit.

### 1. API.java

```
public interface API {
@Multipart
    @POST("user_login_by_mob")
    Call<LoginCallBack> login(@Part("email") RequestBody email, @Part("first_name") RequestBody first_name, @Part("last_name") RequestBody last_name, @Part("phone") RequestBody phone , @Part MultipartBody.Part profile_picture);
}
```

### 2. SelectLoginActivity.java

```
public void apiCallForFBLogin(String Email_Id, String Fname, String Lname, String Phone_No, String Profile_Pic){
        if (NetworkUtils.getConnectivityStatus(SelectLoginActivity.this)!=0) {
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Please Wait.....");
            dialog.show();
            API api = App.retrofit.create(API.class);
            File file1 = new File(Profile_Pic);
            RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file1);


            MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("profile_picture", file1.getName(), requestBody);
            RequestBody mail_id = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), Email_Id);
            RequestBody fnm = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), Fname);
            RequestBody lnm = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), Lname);
            RequestBody pnm = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), Phone_No);

            final Call<LoginCallBack> loginCallBackCall = api.login(mail_id,fnm,lnm,pnm,body);

            loginCallBackCall.enqueue(new Callback<LoginCallBack>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<LoginCallBack> call, Response<LoginCallBack> response) {
                    if (dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                    if (response.code()==200){
                      if (response.body().getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("success")){

                          Functions.setStringPrefData(SelectLoginActivity.this,FindExperience.USER_ID,response.body().getUserId());

                          Intent i = new Intent(SelectLoginActivity.this,HomeActivity.class);
                          overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
                          startActivity(i);
                          finish();
                      }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<LoginCallBack> call, Throwable t) {
                    if (dialog.isShowing() && dialog != null) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(SelectLoginActivity.this, t.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.d("TAG", "onFailure: " + t.getLocalizedMessage());
                }
            });

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(SelectLoginActivity.this, "Please check your internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }
```

Also i try to pass image with Asyntask

```
private class UploadFileToServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {
        Context c;
        String Email_ID;
        String fname;
        String lname;
        String phone;
        String ImagePath;

        public UploadFileToServer(Context c, String Email_ID, String fname, String lname, String phone, String ImagePath) {
            this.Email_ID = Email_ID;
            this.fname = fname;
            this.lname = lname;
            this.ImagePath = ImagePath;
            this.phone = phone;
            this.c = c;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // setting progress bar to zero
//            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//            progressBar.setProgress(0);
//             d=ProgressDialog.show(c,"","Pease Wait");
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(SelectLoginActivity.this, "", "Please Wait...");
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.show();
//               d.show();
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            return uploadFile();
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        private String uploadFile() {
            String webAddressToPost = "http://phpstack-51492-281292.cloudwaysapps.com/Api/user_login_by_mob";
            String responseString = null;
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(webAddressToPost);

            try {
                org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity entity = new org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity(
                        HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
                Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(ImagePath));
                Log.d("TAG", "uploadFile: " + ImagePath);
                File sourceFile = new File(fileUri.getPath());
                entity.addPart("email", new StringBody(Email_ID));
                entity.addPart("first_name", new StringBody(fname));
                entity.addPart("last_name", new StringBody(lname));
                entity.addPart("phone", new StringBody(phone));
                entity.addPart("profile_picture", new FileBody(sourceFile));

//                totalSize = entity.getContentLength();
                httppost.setEntity(entity);

                // Making server call
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();

                int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                if (statusCode == 200) {
                    // Server response
                    responseString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);
                } else {
                    responseString = "Error occurred! Http Status Code: "
                            + statusCode;
                }

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                responseString = e.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                responseString = e.toString();
            }

            return responseString;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            Log.e("TAG", "Response from server: " + result);

//            try {
//                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result);
//                JSONObject objData = obj.getJSONObject("meta");
//
//                if (objData.getString("code").equals("RESP_OKAY")) {
//                    Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, objData.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("USER_PROFILE", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
//                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
//                    editor.putString(Const.USER_PROFILE_IMG, obj.getString("profile_picture"));
//                    editor.commit();
//                } else if (objData.getString("code").equals("error")) {
//                    Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, objData.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                }
//            } catch (Exception e) {
//                e.printStackTrace();
//            }
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

    }
```

### 3.Logcat

```
06-19 16:28:26.803 16965-16965/com.example.find.findexperience D/TAG: onSuccess: {AccessToken token:ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED permissions:[email, public_profile]}
06-19 16:28:27.193 16965-16965/com.example.find.findexperience D/TAG: Profile Added
06-19 16:28:27.233 16965-17034/com.example.find.findexperience D/TAG: uploadFile: https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/19227_627218584084664_6650113733416458428_n.jpg?oh=67ade1c20fba9dbf6359ae2f92037733&oe=59DD4519
06-19 16:28:27.644 16965-16965/com.example.find.findexperience D/TAG: onFailure: /https:/scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/19227_627218584084664_6650113733416458428_n.jpg?oh=67ade1c20fba9dbf6359ae2f92037733&oe=59DD4519: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
06-19 16:28:28.204 16965-16965/com.example.find.findexperience E/TAG: Response from server: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /https:/scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/19227_627218584084664_6650113733416458428_n.jpg?oh=67ade1c20fba9dbf6359ae2f92037733&oe=59DD4519: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Why Url format is changed when i calling api

We can see both correct and wrong format in Logcat file

Correct format is :uploadFile: https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/19227_627218584084664_6650113733416458428_n.jpg?oh=67ade1c20fba9dbf6359ae2f92037733&oe=59DD4519

Wrong Format is : onFailure: /https:/scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/19227_627218584084664_6650113733416458428_n.jpg?oh=67ade1c20fba9dbf6359ae2f92037733&oe=59DD4519: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: My problem is when is calling api then image url format is changed, you can see my edited question, i specified correct and wrong format both

Comment: I guess this is the Permission issue.Make sure you give the storage permission for read or write.

Comment: i gave both permission
` <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` in manifest file

Comment: Where you store your file where is the code for storing an image?

Comment: i m not storing img in external storage

Comment: Store your file in your app directory or some other directory and then try to upload the image. After successful upload delete the file from that directory if you don't need it.

Comment: Storing image is compulsory?

Comment: Yes because when image is uploading it read bytes from the image file and then completing the byte reading it upload image to server.

Comment: i downloaded image and now i pass external storage directory path when i call api..then why i cant get profile picture link in response?

Comment: First you need to store Facebook profile picture in external storage or internal storage then when you call API you need to pass that storage directory path to your API.